# Community redirect not working when user clicks on link on page but works when URL entered directly in browser address bar

Tags: redirect

I setup a relative redirect via Salesforce Community SiteBuilder.  The redirect works successfully if I enter the URL directly in the browser address bar and press enter.  However, if I have the "From" URL as a link in a Lightning component that a user clicks on, he is not redirected to the "To" URL.  I don't understand why he isn't being redirected since the redirect is setup and works when entered in the browser address bar.

The code in the Lightning component is

```
<a href="{!v.sitePath+v.newsURL+news.Id}">{!news.Name}</a>
```

Comment: where is she/he being redirected to? what's the format of the "Name" variable? Have you tried appending &isdtp=p1 to the url?

Comment: @CasparHarmer  I didn't realize that the Lightning component code got chopped off when I put it into Stack Exchange.  It is "<a href="{!v.sitePath+v.newsURL+news.Id}">{!news.Name}</a> "  

I haven't tried appending &isdtp=p1  What does that do?  I will also research it.

Comment: It tells sf that you are coming from lightning - I see the url now - fixed your question